# How to add to the prototype of types from other modules in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, prototypal-inheritance

Let's say I would like to add this method onto `String`:

```
String.prototype.frenchQuote = function() {
  return '« ' + this + ' »';
}
```

TypeScript will complain that there is no `frenchQuote` method on `String`.

Online, many suggestions can be found to then declare it like so:

```
interface String {
  frenchQuote(): string
}
```

However, TypeScript flags this `interface` as unused, and still complains about the non-existent method.

Is there a new way to augment the signature of imported types or built-ins?

*Using TypeScript version* **3.7**

Comment: you might just need to specify a namespace (global, window?) so it picks up the interface

Comment: @VladGincher none of the answers are accepted there, and the most upvoted one doesn't seem to work in TypeScript 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @pushkin for the hint. The solution was to signal to TS that the `interface` is global:

```
declare global {
  interface String {
    frenchQuote(): string
  }
}
```